# increment date by one month

Tags: php, date

Let's say I have a date in the following format: 2010-12-11 (year-mon-day)

With PHP, I want to increment the date by one month, and I want the year to be automatically incremented, if necessary (i.e. incrementing from December 2012 to January 2013).

Regards.

Comment: check this question as well guys. it is similar to this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72442475/how-to-increment-date-by-one-month-in-laravel

Answer (score 204, accepted):

```
$time = strtotime("2010.12.11");
$final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));

// Finally you will have the date you're looking for.
```

Comment: It doesn't work with all date. For example 2013-05-31 will display July instead of the next month which is June.

Comment: I am getting following , 2014-03-03 for 2014-01-31 reason?

Comment: It didn't work with this string: "2014-06-19 15:00:19"

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php Y-M-D is strtotime("2010.12.11"); *( dots, not dashes )

Comment: This does break sometimes. The answer by @jason is technically more correct since it accounts for things like leap years, month lengths, and so on. That should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: this answer is dangerous because it fails on "last day of the month" scenarios which is hard to detect.

Answer (score 53):

I needed similar functionality, except for a monthly cycle (plus months, minus 1 day). After searching S.O. for a while, I was able to craft this plug-n-play solution:

```
function add_months($months, DateTime $dateObject) 
    {
        $next = new DateTime($dateObject->format('Y-m-d'));
        $next->modify('last day of +'.$months.' month');

        if($dateObject->format('d') > $next->format('d')) {
            return $dateObject->diff($next);
        } else {
            return new DateInterval('P'.$months.'M');
        }
    }

function endCycle($d1, $months)
    {
        $date = new DateTime($d1);

        // call second function to add the months
        $newDate = $date->add(add_months($months, $date));

        // goes back 1 day from date, remove if you want same day of month
        $newDate->sub(new DateInterval('P1D')); 

        //formats final date to Y-m-d form
        $dateReturned = $newDate->format('Y-m-d'); 

        return $dateReturned;
    }
```

Example:

```
$startDate = '2014-06-03'; // select date in Y-m-d format
$nMonths = 1; // choose how many months you want to move ahead
$final = endCycle($startDate, $nMonths); // output: 2014-07-02
```

Comment: Excellent, just what I needed. Thanks for saving me a lot of time!

Comment: No problem, glad you found it useful

Comment: Thanks Jason, this was very helpful. I reformatted it and added more comments to help me understand it all. In case that helps anyone, I have posted it further down (tried to add it here but it was too long).

Comment: it gives same value for 30 Jan and 31 Jan though!

Comment: Works like a charm, just tested it for 2020 Jan 1 through Dec 31, thanks!

Comment: If you use that for subscription periods remember to add one day to the start of the next period. Otherwise your subscriptions will overlap by one day and it will constantly move ahead by that one day. 

```$next_subscription_from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($last_subscription_to+24*60*60);```

Comment: This is perfect, except that I have to change to `$next = new DateTime($dateObject->format('c'));` to get the same o'clock time

Comment: This suffers from the same problem as HRoux'es answer.
2023-02-01: 2023-02-28,
2023-03-01: 2023-03-31
2023-04-01: 2023-04-30
I added the correct answer. Hopefully :)

Answer (score 38):

Use [`DateTime::add`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).

```
$start = new DateTime("2010-12-11", new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
$month_later = clone $start;
$month_later->add(new DateInterval("P1M"));
```

I used [clone](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php) because add modifies the original object, which might not be desired.

Comment: does not work.. (new DateTime("2010-01-31", new DateTimeZone("UTC")))->add(new DateInterval("P1M"))->format('Y-m-d') results in 2010-03-03

Answer (score 14):

```
strtotime( "+1 month", strtotime( $time ) );
```

this returns a timestamp that can be used with the date function

Comment: @Gelen : this doesn't works, gives wrong date....please tell how to use your method , what's the value of $time here?

Comment: this doesn't works, gives wrong date....please tell how to use your method , what's the value of $time here?

Comment: Same problem as accepted answer. Doesn't work on all strings.

Comment: this works for me (of course `$time` has an initial value).

Answer (score 14):

You can use `DateTime::modify` like this :

```
$date = new DateTime('2010-12-11');
$date->modify('+1 month');
```

See documentations :

https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

https://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

---

**UPDATE january 2021 : correct mistakes raised by comments**

This solution has some problems for months with 31 days like May etc.

*Exemple : this jumps from 31st May to 1st July which is incorrect.*

To correct that, you can create this custom function

```
function addMonths($date,$months){
    
    $init=clone $date;
    $modifier=$months.' months';
    $back_modifier =-$months.' months';
   
    $date->modify($modifier);
    $back_to_init= clone $date;
    $back_to_init->modify($back_modifier);
   
    while($init->format('m')!=$back_to_init->format('m')){
        $date->modify('-1 day')    ;
        $back_to_init= clone $date;
        $back_to_init->modify($back_modifier);   
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like that :

```
$date = new DateTime('2010-05-31');
addMonths($date, 1);
print_r($date);
//DateTime Object ( [date] => 2010-06-30 00:00:00.000000 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => Europe/Berlin )
```

This solution was found in PHP.net posted by jenspj : https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.modify.php#107592

Comment: this jumps from 31st May to 1st July which is incorrect

Comment: Still broken: `php > var_dump((new DateTime('2010-05-31'))->modify('+1 month'));
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2010-07-01 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
`

Comment: Doenst work with this case:
$date = new DateTime('2013-05-31');
$date->modify('+1 month');

Answer (score 8):

```
(date('d') > 28) ? date("mdY", strtotime("last day of next month")) : date("mdY", strtotime("+1 month"));
```

This will compensate for February and the other 31 day months.  You could of course do a lot more checking to to get more exact for 'this day next month' [relative date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) (which does not work sadly, see below), and you could just as well use DateTime.

Both `DateInterval('P1M')` and `strtotime("+1 month")` are essentially blindly adding 31 days regardless of the number of days in the following month.

- 2010-01-31 => March 3rd
- 2012-01-31 => March 2nd (leap year)

Comment: "blindly adding 31 days regardless of the number of days in the following month", absolutely right! (+1).

Answer (score 7):

Please first you set your date format as like 12-12-2012

After use this function it's work properly;

```
$date =  date('d-m-Y',strtotime("12-12-2012 +2 Months");
```

Here 12-12-2012 is your date and +2 Months is increment of the month;

You also increment of Year, Date

```
strtotime("12-12-2012 +1 Year");
```

Ans is 12-12-2013

Answer (score 5):

I use this way:-

```
 $occDate='2014-01-28';
 $forOdNextMonth= date('m', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($occDate)));
//Output:- $forOdNextMonth=02


/*****************more example****************/
$occDate='2014-12-28';

$forOdNextMonth= date('m', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($occDate)));
//Output:- $forOdNextMonth=01

//***********************wrong way**********************************//
$forOdNextMonth= date('m', strtotime("+1 month", $occDate));
  //Output:- $forOdNextMonth=02; //instead of $forOdNextMonth=01;
//******************************************************************//
```

Comment: it work for me thanks. But, date('m', strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($occDate))) and date('m', strtotime("+1 month", $occDate)) work same.

Comment: No, both is difference @sah.cyBuzzSc. Consider example:-  $occDate='2014-12-28'; $forOdNextMonth= date('m', strtotime("+1 month", $occDate)); The value $forOdNextMonth is 02.

Comment: thanks for explain @chotesah. Your second example is quite good.

Answer (score 5):

Just updating the answer with simple method for find the date after no of months. As the best answer marked doesn't give the correct solution.

```
<?php

    $date = date('2020-05-31');
    $current = date("m",strtotime($date));
    $next = date("m",strtotime($date."+1 month"));
    if($current==$next-1){
        $needed = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date." +1 month"));
    }else{
        $needed = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last day of next month",strtotime($date)));
    }
    echo "Date after 1 month from 2020-05-31 would be : $needed";

?>
```

Comment: Only This is the correct solution for +1 month date.

Comment: This will not work for December.

Comment: This technically does give you the correct month, but what's with the jumping between days? :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the date of one month from now you can do it like this

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('1 month'));
```

If you want to get the date of two months from now, you can achieve that by doing this

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2 month'));
```

And so on, that's all.

Comment: It doesn't work with all date. For example 2013-05-31 will display July instead of the next month which is June

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @NetVicious i corrected the code, it should work with all dates, some example:

2013-01-30 will be 2013-02-28

2013-05-15 will be 2013-05-15

2013-05-31 will be 2013-06-30

This code uses the DateTime class to create a new date object, then it adds 1 month to the date using the modify method. Next, it gets the day of the next month using the format method. If the next month's day doesn't match the original day, it modifies the date to the last day of the previous month using the modify method.

```
$original_date = "2013-01-30";
$original_day = date("d", strtotime($original_date));

$date = new DateTime($original_date);
$date->modify('+1 month');
$next_month_day = $date->format('d');

if ($next_month_day != $original_day) {
  $date->modify('last day of previous month');
}

$new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $new_date;
```

Comment: Correct. Strictly speaking this is THE answer to the question. I did add another reply to generalize upon the concept, however.

Comment: That's wrong. If $date = '2013-05-15' you will be adding more than one month.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason, your post was very helpful. I reformatted it and added more comments to help me understand it all. In case that helps anyone, I have posted it here:

```
function cycle_end_date($cycle_start_date, $months) {
    $cycle_start_date_object = new DateTime($cycle_start_date);

    //Find the date interval that we will need to add to the start date
    $date_interval = find_date_interval($months, $cycle_start_date_object);

    //Add this date interval to the current date (the DateTime class handles remaining complexity like year-ends)
    $cycle_end_date_object = $cycle_start_date_object->add($date_interval);

    //Subtract (sub) 1 day from date
    $cycle_end_date_object->sub(new DateInterval('P1D')); 

    //Format final date to Y-m-d
    $cycle_end_date = $cycle_end_date_object->format('Y-m-d'); 

    return $cycle_end_date;
}

//Find the date interval we need to add to start date to get end date
function find_date_interval($n_months, DateTime $cycle_start_date_object) {
    //Create new datetime object identical to inputted one
    $date_of_last_day_next_month = new DateTime($cycle_start_date_object->format('Y-m-d'));

    //And modify it so it is the date of the last day of the next month
    $date_of_last_day_next_month->modify('last day of +'.$n_months.' month');

    //If the day of inputted date (e.g. 31) is greater than last day of next month (e.g. 28)
    if($cycle_start_date_object->format('d') > $date_of_last_day_next_month->format('d')) {
        //Return a DateInterval object equal to the number of days difference
        return $cycle_start_date_object->diff($date_of_last_day_next_month);
    //Otherwise the date is easy and we can just add a month to it
    } else {
        //Return a DateInterval object equal to a period (P) of 1 month (M)
        return new DateInterval('P'.$n_months.'M');
    }
}

$cycle_start_date = '2014-01-31'; // select date in Y-m-d format
$n_months = 1; // choose how many months you want to move ahead
$cycle_end_date = cycle_end_date($cycle_start_date, $n_months); // output: 2014-07-02
```

Comment: Hi, any limitations to this for months with 31 days ? or 28 days ? Also any improvements for adding multiple months ?

Comment: No, this does not work at all. 2023-02-01, 2023-03-01 etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
function dayOfWeek($date){
    return DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->format('N');
}
```

Usage examples:

```
echo dayOfWeek(2016-12-22);
// "4"
echo dayOfWeek(date('Y-m-d'));
// "4"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strtotime("2017-12-11");
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $date));
```

If you want to increment by days you can also do it

```
$date = strtotime("2017-12-11");
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+5 day", $date));
```

Comment: It doesn't work with all date. For example 2013-05-31 will display July instead of the next month which is June

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to any date format.

```
echo date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', '15/04/2017')->add(new DateInterval('P1M'))->format('d/m/Y');
```

Just change the date format.

Answer (score 0):

```
//ECHO MONTHS BETWEEN TWO TIMESTAMPS
$my_earliest_timestamp = 1532095200;
$my_latest_timestamp = 1554991200;

echo '<pre>';
echo "Earliest timestamp: ". date('c',$my_earliest_timestamp) ."\r\n";
echo "Latest timestamp: " .date('c',$my_latest_timestamp) ."\r\n\r\n";

echo "Month start of earliest timestamp: ". date('c',strtotime('first day of '. date('F Y',$my_earliest_timestamp))) ."\r\n";
echo "Month start of latest timestamp: " .date('c',strtotime('first day of '. date('F Y',$my_latest_timestamp))) ."\r\n\r\n";

echo "Month end of earliest timestamp: ". date('c',strtotime('last day of '. date('F Y',$my_earliest_timestamp)) + 86399) ."\r\n";
echo "Month end of latest timestamp: " .date('c',strtotime('last day of '. date('F Y',$my_latest_timestamp)) + 86399) ."\r\n\r\n";

$sMonth = strtotime('first day of '. date('F Y',$my_earliest_timestamp));
$eMonth = strtotime('last day of '. date('F Y',$my_earliest_timestamp)) + 86399;
$xMonth = strtotime('+1 month', strtotime('first day of '. date('F Y',$my_latest_timestamp)));

while ($eMonth < $xMonth) {
    echo "Things from ". date('Y-m-d',$sMonth) ." to ". date('Y-m-d',$eMonth) ."\r\n\r\n";
    $sMonth = $eMonth + 1; //add 1 second to bring forward last date into first second of next month.
    $eMonth = strtotime('last day of '. date('F Y',$sMonth)) + 86399;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I find the mtkime() function works really well for this:

```php
$start_date="2021-10-01";
$start_date_plus_a_month=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m",strtotime($start_date))+1, date("d",strtotime($start_date)), date("Y",strtotime($start_date))));
```

result: 2021-11-01

I like to subtract 1 from the 'day' to produce '2021-10-31' which can be useful if you want to display a range across 12 months, e.g. Oct 1, 2021 to Sep 30 2022

```php
$start_date_plus_a_year=date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m",strtotime($start_date))+12, date("d",strtotime($start_date))-1, date("Y",strtotime($start_date))));
```

result: 2022-09-30

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to the exact question asked is Giuseppe Canale's answer from earlier. I'm going to answer a slightly more generic question of how to increment the date by an arbitrary number of months, however.

```
<?php    
/**
 * Will return a timestamp corresponding to first day of the month that is N months into the future.
 * @param int $months_later number of months into the future: 0 for current one
 * @param string $today if supplied will be used as the "now" time
 * @return int
 */
function rel_month_to_time($months_later, $today=null) {
    if ($months_later===0) {
        return is_null($today) ? time() : strtotime($today);
    }
    return strtotime('first day of next month', rel_month_to_time($months_later-1, $today));
}
```

As is many times the case, you can use recursion for these "human problems" like calendars. The above can be used to return a timestamp corresponding to "next month" -- the way we humans think of it.

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d', rel_month_to_time(1, '2023-01-30'));
// 2023-02-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly easier method is to start your calculation from the 1st day of the current month, add your month(s), ***then*** get the last day of that month, example:

```
$now = "2023-01-31";
$add_months = 1;
$last_day_of_month = date("Y-m-t", strtotime($now));  

if ($now == $last_day_of_month) {

    //Need to use a some custom logic, because +1 months will fail if the start date is equal to the last day of the month... 
    //Start calculation from first day of this month, then get the last day of next month(s)
    $now = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("first day of this month", strtotime($now)));

    //note the Y-m-t --not-- Y-m-d
    $final = date('Y-m-t', strtotime("+".$add_months." months", strtotime($now)));

} else {
    //The start date isn't the last day of the month, we can use the normal +months functionality
    $final = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$add_months." months", strtotime($now)));
}


Input: 2023-01-31
Output: 2023-02-28

Input: 2023-03-31
Output: 2023-04-30

Input: 2024-01-31 (leap year test)
Output: 2024-02-29
```

Tested up to year: 2157 (A.I. will probably figure this out by then, haha).
Change your $now starting date, and number of $add_months if needed.

Answer (score -2):

put a date in input box then click the button get day from date in jquery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("button").click(function(){   
    var day = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
    var a = new Date();
    $(".result").text(day[a.getDay()]);

    });  
             });
```

Answer (score -2):

All presented solutions **are not working properly.**
strtotime() and [DateTime::add](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) or [DateTime::modify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) give sometime invalid results.
Examples:
- 31.08.2019 + 1 month gives 01.10.2019 instead 30.09.2019
- 29.02.2020 + 1 year gives 01.03.2021 instead 28.02.2021
(tested on PHP 5.5, PHP 7.3)

Below is my function based on [idea posted by Angelo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php#118342) that solves the problem:

```
// $time - unix time or date in any format accepted by strtotime() e.g. 2020-02-29  
// $days, $months, $years - values to add
// returns new date in format 2021-02-28
function addTime($time, $days, $months, $years)
{
    // Convert unix time to date format
    if (is_numeric($time))
    $time = date('Y-m-d', $time);

    try
    {
        $date_time = new DateTime($time);
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    if ($days)
    $date_time->add(new DateInterval('P'.$days.'D'));

    // Preserve day number
    if ($months or $years)
    $old_day = $date_time->format('d');

    if ($months)
    $date_time->add(new DateInterval('P'.$months.'M'));

    if ($years)
    $date_time->add(new DateInterval('P'.$years.'Y'));

    // Patch for adding months or years    
    if ($months or $years)
    {
        $new_day = $date_time->format("d");

        // The day is changed - set the last day of the previous month
        if ($old_day != $new_day)
        $date_time->sub(new DateInterval('P'.$new_day.'D'));
    }
    // You can chage returned format here
    return $date_time->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Usage examples:

```
echo addTime('2020-02-29', 0, 0, 1); // add 1 year (result: 2021-02-28)
echo addTime('2019-08-31', 0, 1, 0); // add 1 month (result: 2019-09-30)
echo addTime('2019-03-15', 12, 2, 1); // add 12 days, 2 months, 1 year (result: 2019-09-30)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 <?php
              $selectdata ="select fromd,tod  from register where username='$username'";
            $q=mysqli_query($conm,$selectdata);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($q);

            $startdate=$row['fromd']; 
            $stdate=date('Y', strtotime($startdate));  

            $endate=$row['tod']; 
            $enddate=date('Y', strtotime($endate));  

            $years = range ($stdate,$enddate);
            echo '<select name="years" class="form-control">';
            echo '<option>SELECT</option>';
            foreach($years as $year)
              {   echo '<option value="'.$year.'"> '.$year.' </option>';  }
                echo '</select>'; ?>
```

Comment: Copy pasting code does not always help. You should also explain the code a bit.