# How to increment date with 1 (day/year) in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a date stored in an array:

```
$this->lines['uDate']
```

The format of the date is not fixed. I can be changed with this:

```
  define('DATETIME_FORMAT', 'y-m-d H:i');
```

How can I increment my uDate with a certain number of days or years?

---

My question is related to this one:
[increment date by one month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870295/increment-date-by-one-month)
However, in my case the date format in dynamic.
So, can I do this?

```
$time= $this->lines['uDate'];
$time = date(DATETIME_FORMAT, strtotime("+1 day", $time));
$this->lines['uDate']= $time;
```

Comment: I would look in to storing the raw date value somewhere so you can further manipulate it, otherwise you're going to get in to a huge amount of trouble re-inventing the "date parser" routine.

Comment: Constants aren't interpolated in quotes.  Call `date(DATETIME_FORMAT)`, not `date("DATETIME_FORMAT")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function add_date($givendate,$day=0,$mth=0,$yr=0) 
{
      $cd = strtotime($givendate);
      $newdate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', mktime(date('h',$cd),
    date('i',$cd), date('s',$cd), date('m',$cd)+$mth,
    date('d',$cd)+$day, date('Y',$cd)+$yr));
      return $newdate;
}
```

I have found this in PHP help

Answer (score 4):

[date_add()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php)

and consider changes like:

```
define(DATETIME_FORMAT, 'y-m-d H:i');

$time = date(DATETIME_FORMAT, strtotime("+1 day", $time));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use some simple calculation to do it if you have the timestamp.

```
$date = strtotime($this->lines['uDate']); //assuming it's not a timestamp\
$date = $date + (60 * 60 * 24); //increase date by 1 day
echo  date('d-m-y', $date);
$date = $date + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365); //increase date by a year
echo  date('d-m-y', $date);
```

You can also use the mktime() method to do this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score 0):

another useful way, if you want an object rather than a string:

```
$date = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2022-01-05'); // just an exemplary date

$date = $date->add(date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 day')); // count up
```

notable difference:

date_add() changes the original object, while DateTimeImmutable::add() does not and simply returns the new object. Depending on the desired behavior, use one or the other.