# Auto increment years in loop every year

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increment date with 1 (day/year) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381330/how-to-increment-date-with-1-day-year-in-php)

Im not really sure where to begin with this but im trying to make a year start at 1928 and stop at 1948 and for every year the years increment by one so since its 2012 the date ranges are 1928 - 1948 and for 2013 it would be 1929 - 1949 and 2014 would be 1930 - 1950 and so on...

right now i just have a basic loop for when to start and stop the years but its not too dynamic, like i said im pretty much at a blank on where to begin other then date('Y')+1.

```
for($i=1928;$i<=date('Y');$i++)
{
    echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
    if($i == '1948'){break;}
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So you want it to go between current year minus 84 and the current year minus 64?  Use this code:

```
$firstYear = (int)date('Y') - 84;
$lastYear = $firstYear + 20;
for($i=$firstYear;$i<=$lastYear;$i++)
{
    echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}
```

Edit: updated for performance.  Current year is determined before the loop (per Pitchinnate's comment).

Comment: looks like the start year changes too in his example

Comment: That is still having to evaluate the max and min every time through the loop ($currentYear - 64)

Comment: Ahh, I suppose it is.  I changed it again.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$year = date('Y');
$add = $year - 2012;
$min = 1928 + $add;
$max = $min + 20;
for($i=$min;$i<=$max;$i++)
{
    echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}
```

I isn't a good idea to have date('Y') or any evaluations done on the for loop as it gets calculated every time through the loop. [Article](http://www.codeforest.net/php-mythbusters-count-inside-for-loop-is-slow) about this.

Answer (score 3):

```
for($i =0; $i <= 20 ;$i++)
{
    $year = date('Y') - 84 + $i;
    echo '<option value='.$year.'>'.$year.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
$base_year = 2012;
$start_year = $base_year - 84;
$end_year = $start_year + 20;

for( $i = $start_year; $i <= $end_year; $i++)
{   
    echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a constant with how far back you want the date range to be from the current year that you can use to write a loop that will work for you.

Since it's 2012 now, and you want the range to start at 1928 when it's 2012, then we can use 2012 - 1928 = 84, so the year that starts the range should always be 84 less than the current year.

Therefore we could write code like:

```
$startingYear = date('Y') - 84;
$endingYear = $startingYear + 20;

for ($i = $startingYear;$i <= $endingYear;$i++)
{
    echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}
```