# How can I add dates in PHP

Tags: php, date, strtotime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [increment date by one month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870295/increment-date-by-one-month)

I have the following code to sum dates:

```
$var1 = date("d/m/Y");
$dia = substr($var1,0,2);
$mes = substr($var1,3,2);
$a_o = substr($var1,6,4);
$date = $a_o."-".$mes."-".$dia;
$new_date = strtotime( "+3 month", strtotime($date));
$new_date = date('d/m/Y', $new_date);
echo $new_date;
```

That is the normal method I found on php.net but when I tried to change `$var1` with another date, for example, `'21/07/2020'` the result is `'31/01/1970'`, I don't know what's wrong. I tried many forms but the result is the same.

How can I fix this? Or what other forms exist to add X months to a date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [date_add()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) function that was added for 5.3.0.

> DateTime::add -- date_add — Adds an amount of days, months, years,
>   hours, minutes and seconds to a DateTime object

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

There is also the [date_modify()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) function that was added for 5.2.0.

> DateTime::modify -- date_modify — Alters the timestamp

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
$date->modify('+1 day');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Comment: +1 for setting an OO example while still mentioning the procedural functions

Comment: With that code works, thank you very much!!! :) RobB

Comment: @nanaxr - Glad I could assist.

Answer (score 3):

You're going about it completely wrong. `date()` gives you a nicely formatted **STRING**. If you want to do math with dates, you need to work with the native PHP date/time values, which are simple integers - unix time stamps.

You're taking that unix timestamp (the default value in `date()`), converting it to a string, taking apart that string, recombining the string in a different order, then converting it back to a timestamp, then converting the timestamp into a different formatted string. That's like going on a 500mile road trip so you can cross the street.

Any reason you can't simply do:

```
$new_date = date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+3 month'));
```

and eliminate everything else in your code snippet?

Answer (score -4):

In your place, I'll trasform the date in timestamp, then I'll add the new date in seconds (i.e. 3 months are 60 * 60 * 24 * 90 = 7 776 000 secs.) and then transform back in date :P

Comment: A month isn't necessarily 30-days long.

Comment: In fact, fewer than half of the months are 30 days long.