# php - why I'm always getting the present month with its date after executing this ff loop?

Tags: php, loops, date, for-loop, duration

I have this following loop which would get the dates with a given duration and start date.

```
$durationMonth =$_POST['pay_months']; //how many months to pay
$count = ($durationMonth * 30);
$day = 1;
for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++)
{ 
    $day+=1; 
    $start_date=date("y-m-d");
    $start_date=strtotime(date("y-m-d",strtotime($start_date))." + $day day");
    $start_date=date("y-m-d",$rel_date);

  echo "<tr>
 <td id ='row'> ".$i."</td> 
 <td id ='row'> ".$start_date." </td>
 </tr> ";
}
```

This loop wont work. If I set the ff:

```
 $start_date =  '2015-01-01'
 $duration = 1
```

Even if how many times i tried, this always gives the dates from `15-03-04` up to `15-04-02` . How should I revise my code? Thanks for the help

Comment: Ugly! Use `DateTime()` for date math. *much* cleaner.

Comment: What proportion of the months in a year have 30 days? 4 out of 12! Your code will be wrong 67% of the time

Comment: How should it be done to set also the months having leap year and have 31 days?

Comment: possible duplicate of [increment date by one month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870295/increment-date-by-one-month)

Comment: i just understand the procedural one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I flagged it is [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870295/increment-date-by-one-month) .

So you can try:

```
$durationMonth =$_POST['pay_months']; //how many months to pay
$start_date=strtotime (date("y-m-d"));
for ($i=1; $i<=$durationMonth; $i++)
{ 
  $start_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $start_date));
  echo "<tr>
 <td id ='row'> ".$i."</td> 
 <td id ='row'> ".$start_date." </td>
 </tr> ";
}
```

the only thing you should worry if date day is more than 28.

If you can accept this solution to avoid usin 29,30,31 as a date day :

```
$durationMonth =$_POST['pay_months']; //how many months to pay
$start_date=strtotime (date("y-m-d"));
if (date('j',$start_date)>28)
   $start_date=strtotime (date("y-m-").'28');
for ($i=1; $i<=$durationMonth; $i++)
{ 
  $start_date = strtotime("+1 month", $start_date);
  echo "<tr>
 <td id ='row'> ".$i."</td> 
 <td id ='row'> ". date("Y-m-d", $start_date)." </td>
 </tr> ";
}
```

Comment: It's useful but why is it that my `$start_date = $_POST['start_date'];` is not captured? How it could be set in the code to be my `$start_date=strtotime (date("y-m-d"));`   ?

Comment: because you didn't show in your post that you need that `start_date` from `$_POST`. so if you have it as a post field just change `$start_date=strtotime (date("y-m-d"));` to `$start_date=strtotime ($_POST['start_date']));`

Comment: thank you so much for the help Alex. :) i got it now.