# Adding a month to Date returns wrong day

Tags: php, datetime

I want to add a month to current Date. I found a code here on stackoverflow and it works - but, it returns a wrong day. It removes a day from the current date.

Code:

```
    function add_months($months, DateTime $dateObject) 
        {
            $next = new DateTime($dateObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $next->modify('last day of +'.$months.' month');
            if($dateObject->format('d') > $next->format('d')) {
                return $dateObject->diff($next);
            } else {
                return new DateInterval('P'.$months.'M');
            }
        }

    function endCycle($d1, $months)
        {
            $date = new DateTime($d1);
            $newDate = $date->add(add_months($months, $date));
            $newDate->sub(new DateInterval('P1D')); 
            $dateReturned = $newDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
            return $dateReturned;
        }

$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $today)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo(endCycle($ymd, 1)); //returns wrong day
```

So when I buy a month, I get 29 days. When I buy again, I get -2 days, because it removes the day from the existing expire date in the database.
What´s wrong with the date calculation?..

Thank you :)
Best regards

Comment: Can't you shorten that code to the essential part?

Comment: Edited now. Sorry

Comment: I assume your `endCycle` function was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24014541/2873474)? If yes, please notice the linked answer's output. Working as intended

Comment: Why the mysql tag?

Answer (score -1):

Please, don't overcomplicate a simple task.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime('2006-12-12');
  $date->modify('+1 month');
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

That's all you need.

Comment: "$date = new DateTime('2022-08-31'); $date->modify('+1 month'); echo $date->format('Y-m-d');" try that and you will get "2022-10-01"