# How to increment Month (like Jan, Feb) In php

Tags: php

Let's say I have a date in the following format: Jun-2019 (Month-Year)

With PHP, I want to increment the date by one month, and I want the year to be automatically incremented, if necessary (i.e. increment from December 2019 to January 2020).

Regards.

Comment: Please give your findings or your code that you trying

Comment: $date=date("M-Y", strtotime("+1 month", ''Jan-2019"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\DateInterval` for increment `\DateTime` and then format `\DateTime` to string:

```php
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('M-Y', 'Jun-2019');
$interval = new \DateInterval('P1M');
$date->add($interval);
$dateString = $date->format('M-Y');
```

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/2870298/1839439

Comment: This answer is not fully duplicating the answer because of specific date format