# Incremnet Date By One Month

Tags: php

Let's say I have a date in the following format: 2010-06 (year-mon)

With PHP, I want to increment the date by one month, and I want the year to be automatically incremented, if necessary (i.e. incrementing from December 2012 to January 2013).

i have tried this code

```
$start='2019-06';
for ($i=0; $i < 8 ; $i++) { 
$check_month=strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($start));
echo $start=date('Y-m',$check_month)."<br>";
```

but the output of the code is

```
2019-07
1970-02
1970-02
1970-02
1970-02
1970-02
1970-02
1970-02
```

please suggest the best way

Comment: Do not concat the `<br>` string at the end of the date, else it did not get a valid a date, and on the second loop, you get an invalid date. If you really want to display the date with `br`, save it in var `$start=date('Y-m',$check_month)`, then echo it `echo $start.'<br>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [increment date by one month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870295/increment-date-by-one-month)

Comment: thankz @GrenierJ that solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `->modify` to add months to date. This `$i` is increment variable and add the months to date. `->modify` is pretty fast and easy to use.

```
    $date = new DateTime('now');
    for ($i=1; $i < 9 ; $i++) { 
         $date = new DateTime('now');
         $date->modify("+$i months"); 
         $date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
         echo $date."<br>";
    }
```

Result:

```
2020-02-23
2020-03-23
2020-04-23
2020-05-23
2020-06-23
2020-07-23
2020-08-23
2020-09-23
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use it like this

```
$start='2019-06';
echo date('Y-m',strtotime($start.' + 1 month'));
```

or in a loop

```
$start='2019-06';
foreach(range(1,12) as $o){
    echo date('Y-m',strtotime($start.' + '.$o.' month'))."<br>";
}
```

Output 1

```
2019-07
```

Output 2

```
2019-07
2019-08
2019-09
2019-10
2019-11
2019-12
2020-01
2020-02
2020-03
2020-04
2020-05
2020-06
```