# Given start date get all the months name until current month?

Tags: php

Given start date how to get all the months until current month?

For eg. If given date is 1st Jan 2019

output should be:

```
Jan 2019

Feb 2019

Mar 2019

Apr 2019

May 2019

Jun 2019

Jul 2019

Aug 2019

Sep 2019

Oct 2019

Nov 2019

Dec 2019

Jan 2020

Feb 2020

Mar 2020
```

Solved it with slightly different approach. Thank you all for hints and answers.

```
<?php 

$startTime = strtotime("1 January 2019");
$startYear = date("Y", $startTime);
$currentYear = date("Y");
$yearDiff = $currentYear - $startYear;

$currentMonth = date("m", time());

for($i=0; $i < intval($currentMonth) + ($yearDiff * 12) ; $i++) 
{
$t = strtotime("+". $i . " months", $startTime);
$monthName = date("M", $t) ." ". date('Y', $t);
echo $monthName . "<br/>\n";
} 
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: hint: this is very easy using `DateTime` class with `DateInterval`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [increment date by one month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870295/increment-date-by-one-month)

Comment: No answer yet but thanks for the hints I'm working on it.

Comment: You are telling us what you are expecting, but your code makes no attempt to solve it. StackOverflow is not a free code writing service, so you need to attempt the task before you can have an issue with it requiring help. It may just be a simple case of use. More info at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go , hope this work

```
$start    = new DateTime('2019-01-01');

$end      = new DateTime('2020-03-02');

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($period as $dt) {
echo $dt->format("F Y") . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to use [ISO 8601 duration specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) to create `DateInterval` eg: `$interval = new DateInterval('P1M')`. Also if the date is provided as `1st Jan 2019` you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat('d* M Y', '1st Jan 2019');`